# Flexbox: line break and use of space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here I have a horizontal list of items.

I used flexbox. As I want the items to take only the necessary space at left, I do use `display: flex` and in children `flex: 0;`, as in [Flexbox, line break and stretching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413243/flexbox-line-break-and-stretching).

```css
      ul {
        display: flex;
        padding: 0;
        width: 320px;
        list-style-type: none;
        outline: 4px solid turquoise;
      }
      li {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: 1px solid lightgray;
      }
      span {
        flex: 0;
        outline: 1px solid tomato;
      }
      .svg {
        height: 12px;
        width: 12px;
        outline: 1px solid green;
      }
      svg {
        display: block;
      }
```

```html
<ul>
      <li>
        <span>
          <a href="">123456789</a>
        </span>
        <div class="svg">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path
              d="M7 0a.998.998 0 0 1 .74.327l10 11a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.346l-10 11a1 1 0 0 1-1.48-1.346L15.648 12 6.26 1.673A1 1 0 0 1 7 0z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          <a href="">3456789 123456</a>
        </span>
        <div class="svg">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path
              d="M7 0a.998.998 0 0 1 .74.327l10 11a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.346l-10 11a1 1 0 0 1-1.48-1.346L15.648 12 6.26 1.673A1 1 0 0 1 7 0z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          <a href="">1234 56789 123456 78</a>
        </span>
        <div class="svg">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path
              d="M7 0a.998.998 0 0 1 .74.327l10 11a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.346l-10 11a1 1 0 0 1-1.48-1.346L15.648 12 6.26 1.673A1 1 0 0 1 7 0z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

As you can see, the issue here is that if the text content has a space, flexbox will create a break line without trying to use the remaining space. 
I want to achieve something like this:

[image]
Is it possible to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Give your `li`s a style of `white-space: pre` and your `ul` `display: inline-flex`:

```css
ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  outline: 4px solid turquoise;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 1px solid lightgray;
  white-space: pre;
}

span {
  flex: 0;
  outline: 1px solid tomato;
}

.svg {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>
          <a href="">123456789</a>
        </span>
    <div class="svg">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path
              d="M7 0a.998.998 0 0 1 .74.327l10 11a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.346l-10 11a1 1 0 0 1-1.48-1.346L15.648 12 6.26 1.673A1 1 0 0 1 7 0z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
          <a href="">3456789 123456</a>
        </span>
    <div class="svg">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path
              d="M7 0a.998.998 0 0 1 .74.327l10 11a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.346l-10 11a1 1 0 0 1-1.48-1.346L15.648 12 6.26 1.673A1 1 0 0 1 7 0z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
          <a href="">1234 56789 123456 78</a>
        </span>
    <div class="svg">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path
              d="M7 0a.998.998 0 0 1 .74.327l10 11a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.346l-10 11a1 1 0 0 1-1.48-1.346L15.648 12 6.26 1.673A1 1 0 0 1 7 0z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself properly: I don't want to have only one line, but to adapt the text to the space, so if it needs it, create a breakline. But only if is needed: currently is creating a newline for every space.
In your example no breaklines are created.